# ArgumentException: Parameter cannot be null Parameter name: original in C# code

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

What is wrong in my code?
Whenever I try to iterate through the `IEnumerable` return from this `CompileClasses`. I got error from this line:

```
assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(memoryStream.ToArray());
```

But if I iterate through the object it return I don't got any compile error.

```
 lambda_method(Closure , object , object[] )
    Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(object target, object[] parameters)
```

---

```
  public static IEnumerable<object> CompileClasses(string csharp)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(csharp))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(csharp));
        }


        SyntaxTree tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(csharp);
        CompilationUnitSyntax root = tree.GetCompilationUnitRoot();


        var system = SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName("System");
        var systemCollections = SyntaxFactory.QualifiedName(system, SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName("Collections"));
        var systemCollectionsGeneric = SyntaxFactory.QualifiedName(systemCollections, SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName("Generic"));
        var systemLinq = SyntaxFactory.QualifiedName(system, SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName("Linq"));
        var systemText = SyntaxFactory.QualifiedName(system, SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName("Text"));
        var systemXml = SyntaxFactory.QualifiedName(system, SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName("Xml"));

        var declaredUsings = root.Usings.Select(x => x.Name.ToString()).ToList();
        if (!declaredUsings.Contains("System"))
        {
            root = root.AddUsings(SyntaxFactory.UsingDirective(system).NormalizeWhitespace());
        }
        if (!declaredUsings.Contains("System.Collections"))
        {
            root = root.AddUsings(SyntaxFactory.UsingDirective(systemCollections).NormalizeWhitespace());
        }
        if (!declaredUsings.Contains("System.Collections.Generic"))
        {
            root = root.AddUsings(SyntaxFactory.UsingDirective(systemCollectionsGeneric).NormalizeWhitespace());
        }
        if (!declaredUsings.Contains("System.Linq"))
        {
            root = root.AddUsings(SyntaxFactory.UsingDirective(systemText).NormalizeWhitespace());
        }
        if (!declaredUsings.Contains("System.Text"))
        {
            root = root.AddUsings(SyntaxFactory.UsingDirective(systemLinq).NormalizeWhitespace());
        }
        if (!declaredUsings.Contains("System.Xml"))
        {
            root = root.AddUsings(SyntaxFactory.UsingDirective(systemXml).NormalizeWhitespace());
        }

        tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.Create(root);
        root = tree.GetCompilationUnitRoot();


        var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("CSharp2Json",
            new SyntaxTree[] { tree },

            references: new[]
            {
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location),   MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(Enumerable).Assembly.Location), MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(Uri).Assembly.Location),      MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(DataSet).Assembly.Location),  MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(EntityKey).Assembly.Location),   
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(XmlDocument).Assembly.Location)
            },
            options: new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary)
        );
        System.Console.WriteLine(compilation);
        // load compiled bits into assembly
        Assembly assembly;
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var result = compilation.Emit(memoryStream);
            if (!result.Success)
            {
                throw new System.ArgumentException("Parameter cannot be null", "original");

            }

                assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(memoryStream.ToArray());

        }

        // instantiate object instances from assembly types
        foreach (var definedType in assembly.DefinedTypes)
        {
            Type objType = assembly.GetType(definedType.FullName);
            if (objType.BaseType?.FullName != "System.Enum")
            {
                object instance = null;
                try
                {
                    instance = assembly.CreateInstance(definedType.FullName);
                }
                catch (MissingMethodException)
                {
                    // no default constructor - eat the exception
                }

                if (instance != null)
                {
                    yield return instance;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where do you get the exception?

Comment: I got exception in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(memoryStream.ToArray());

Comment: The stack trace might be useful to know exactly what is throwing the exception...

Comment: I think you (or the debugger) is confused about which line the error is coming from. Look at the line above the line you think it's coming from. It says `throw new System.ArgumentException("Parameter cannot be null", "original");` which would give exactly the error message you are describing. So your `compilation.Emit` is not returning success. By the way, you shouldn't use `"original"` as the second parameter to that exception because it isn't the name of a parameter to that method.